# accessing doc.id in .onWrite firebase cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm triggering a cloud function with onWrite. Within the onWrite function, I want to do something with the ref ID of the document that was written. How can I grab this? My current code looks something like this, but I don't know how to fill eventID.

```
exports.syncEvents = functions.firestore
    .document('events/{eventID}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {

admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(host).collection('events').doc(eventID).set({
            active: true
          })
        });
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`change.after`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Change#after) is a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) of the document that changed, after it was written.  DocumentSnapshot has a property called [`id`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#id) that contains the id of the document.  So `change.after.id` is the document id.

Comment: Great, thanks Doug. I had been trying to use change.after.data().id

Answer (score 0):

The **context** object contains the params of the query.
In your example, the context object will look like this:

```
{
 ...
 params: {
   eventID: "whatever-eventId-is"
 }
 ...
}
```

So you just call get it from the context:

```
const eventId = context.params.eventId;
```

Here is more about context:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions.eventcontext